# If statement is executing when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
function RegisterAction() {
        let saveSub = buyMore(0);
        let askbuyMore = prompt("Do you want to buy more? Y/N ");
        if(askbuyMore === "Y"||"y"||"Yes"||"yes"){
            saveSub = buyMore(saveSub);
            askbuyMore = prompt("Do you want to buy more? Y/N ");
        }else{
            return saveSub;
        }
        const caSalesTax = .0725;
        let caSalesTaxPercent = Math.round((caSalesTax*100)*100)/100;
        let registerTax = console.log(`California sales Tax is ${caSalesTaxPercent}%`);
        registerTax;
        let finalTotalRounded = Math.round(100*(saveSub*caSalesTax+saveSub))/100;
        let registerTotal = console.log(`Your final total with tax is $${finalTotalRounded}.`);
        registerTotal;
    }
```

Why is the if statement executing on first attempt when i aswer askbuyMore prompt with "n"?

Comment: That isn't how you check for multiple matches, off to find a dupetarget explaining it.

Comment: Awesome so how does one do that?

Comment: do i map answers against askbuyMore

Comment: See the linked question's answers. Basically, `if (askbuyMore === "Y" || askbuyMore === "y" askbuyMore === || askbuyMore === "Yes" || askbuyMore === "yes"){` (or a couple of other ways). What you have now does `"Y"||"y"||"Yes"||"yes"`, which evaluates to `"Y"`, and then does `askbuyMore === "Y"`.

Comment: You can do as `["Y", "y", "Yes", "yes"].includes(askbuyMore)`

Comment: Also you don't need to if and an else. Just do an if. So for example if its a no, do the return if true then carry on with the rest of function.

Comment: ok so just add else if statements then